# Can't customize admin template

Tags: python, django

I want to customize the admin template. This is what I did:

1. Created a folder for the new template `C:/xampp/htdocs/myblog/templates/admin`
2. Copied the standard template from `C:\Python27\Lib\site packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\admin\base_site.html`
3. Edited the copied template
4. Configured django to use the new template (added to new directory to `TEMPLATE_DIRS` in `settings.py`)

   ```
   TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
      'C:/xampp/htdocs/myblog/templates'
   )
   ```

This is all there is to do according to the [*Django documentation*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial02/)

I also tried restarting the server, which didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure in step 1 the slash is forward? Typo?

Comment: Yeah, well I tried many times, searching for errors and comparing my code with the documentation and it turns out, i actually wrote the directory name wrong in the config file. This case can be closed.